# What's the maximum wattage that can be used to charge AirPods - both via Lightning and wirelessly?

Tags: charging, airpods

Unlike iOS devices, I haven't been able to easily find the answer to this. Is there any official documentation from Apple or any test results that outline the maximum wattage that AirPods will accept whilst charging - both via Lightning and when charging the case wirelessly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AirPods charge at a maximum of 5W over Lightning or wirelessly.

Connecting the case to a faster charger (for example an Apple 18W charger) is perfectly okay, but the case still won't charger faster.